# Get children errors in a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Good morning,

I've searched through SO for similiar subjects, but none of them work.

In my Sf2.4 I've got this in a controller:

```
$response = array('status' => 'failure');
        $errors = $form->getErrors();
        foreach($form->all() as $child) {
            $errors = array_merge($errors, $child->getErrors());
            var_dump(($child->getErrors()));
        }
```

But the `$errors` variable is always an empty array, even though with:

```
$form->getErrorsAsString();
```

I do see some errors. Why doesn't it get the errors for children nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're digging into https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/9918 If you want all form errors, you need to make it yourself manually by iterating recursively on each form child...

EDIT:

Something like that should do the trick:

```
function getErrors($form) {
    $errors = $form->getErrors();

    foreach ($form as $child) {
        $errors = array_merge($errors, getErrors($child));
    }

    return $errors;
}

$errors = getErrors($form);
```

Comment: Sorry... could you provide an example? I think I'm already iterating over children?

Comment: See my edit, you're iterating over child but on a single level not fully recursively.